# is it better to use DDR4 Ram Instead of the Old DDR3 to Prevent data Corruption?

Tags: windows-10, memory, file-transfer

I have my Gaming PC which has DDR4 Memory RAM with i7 6700k and my Server Which has DDR3 ram with i5 3570k both running Windows 10 Pro without any kind of RAID now I transferred 4 TB of data from my gaming PC to my Windows 10 Server which has an old 16gb DDR3 RAM using my local network. I read on the Internet that DDR3 does not has any kind of protection of data corruption unlike the DDR4 which has CRC feature that ensures that data is written properly to memory without corruption

So my Question is the chance of data corruption bigger when moving a lot of data to a PC Which has an old DDR3 memory? Is it time to upgrade my server to DDR4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not important. I assume I mean transferring data from one hard drive (on the DDR4 PC) to another HD (on the DDR3 PC). Simply speaking the file transfer protocol will check if the data has been copied/moved correctly from one HD to another which includes everything that happened "in-between" like storing and reading from RAM.

The problems that can lead to data corruption won't be removed sufficiently by upgrading the RAM. You can use a tool like Robocopy that has the option to do additional checks if the data has been copied without alterations. Or you can do it manually by creating checksums (MD5, SHA-1, etc.) after you copied the data.

Also important: implement backup and RAID. Failing to do so  - in my experience - leads much more often to data loss.

Comment: thanks the Reason I asked is because I Read that ddr3 ram Can corrupt the data very easily before sending it to the Hard Drive Unlike DDR4 Ram im Not sure if that's right or Not ?im talking about DDR4 and DDR3 desktop Ram.

Comment: @Mariah242 If DDR3 were that unreliable we would not have been using it for the best part of 10 years. There have been some cases of badly manufactured sticks, and of motherboards with faults, but that doesn't mean that DDR3 itself is inherently flawed.

Comment: @Mariah242 There are many other ways the data can get corrupted as well. As I said, the file transfer protokoll will see to it that corrupted data blocks will be copied again, regardless of why they got corrupted

Comment: That's not always true. If they got corrupted when reading from disk to memory on the source system, then "the" file transfer protocol (whichever one you meant) won't have a chance to notice anything -- it'll just generate a checksum based on the already corrupted data. If it got corrupted after receiving, but before writing to disk, then the file transfer protocol won't have any chance to fix it either.

Comment: @user1686 exactly, that's why I added "simply speaking" in my answer - and the suggestion to use additional tools to verify the data transfer process. My explanation shouldn't be taken literally. Thanks for pointing that out! I hope this doesn't cause too much confusion.